# Does the Epiphany browser have desktop notifications?

Tags: notification, webapps, notification-area, epiphany

Does the web browser Epiphany have desktop notifications? How I can activate them?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: It probably should, as webkit-based browsers seem to support notifaction. The problem likely that the browser needs to be configured to accept notifications - this could be indicated by [reporting a bug](https://projects-old.gnome.org/epiphany/bugreports.xhtml)